# Reading calculated data from a formula cell with formula RTD in Excel 2007 form Java application

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, poi-hssf, rtd

I am trying to evaluate the cell value of a formula cell [Formula being RTD] in Excel 2007 from my Java code. I have used HSSFFormulaEvaluator class and evaluate() method, the standard way in short. Add, subtract and other simple functions are working correctly but when I print thw CellValue object on the console returned after evaluation of function RTD, it shows '...[~FUNCTION-NOT-IMPLEMENTED~]'. I suspect POI's HSSFFormulaEvaluator hasn't yet implemented the RTD function. Nevertheless, any help or comment will be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Could you just set the file to force recalculation when Excel opens it? Otherwise, would you be willing to go about implementing this missing function?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are trying to say here. Please elaborate. I unblocked firwewall for eclipse as well, but rtd function is not getting executed. I checked the cell's type and the formula as well. The cell's type is right i.e. HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA and the formula being ' =RTD("XLEnvt.XChng",,"17#1#6069#USDINRCOMP#BID") ' which is correct too. Urgent help required. Do leave a comment. Cheers.

Comment: PS I don't really need to evaluate the formula. Even if the code can just give me whatever is displayed in the actual excel file, it is fine.

Comment: It's not clear on what you want? Do you want to read the last value that Excel calculated? Or do you want excel to show a new value when you open the file?

Comment: The values in the excel file are continuously changing. Once the excel file is open, my application fetches cell values at regular intervals while the excel file is still open [The application fetches the value for precisely 10 times]. These cells are formula cells with formula RTD [+ Appropriate arguments]. However, the Java code is unable to execute this RTD function while it can execute simple add, subtract, max, etc. functions. I am working with POI.

Comment: Seriously mate, I need help and urgently. Do reply.

Comment: @OscarOrcas hey I face same problem can you get anything regarding this?